# Display Only One Category

Tags: php, wordpress

On my WordPress theme, it displays all of the categories a post is in on the homepage for the post block, I only want to display one category even if a post is under multiple categories.

i.e. Category One, Category Two, Category Three

I want it to be Category One...

This is the code that is in place at the moment:

```
<h2><?php the_category(', ') ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category();
echo $category[0]->cat_name;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by first category? The following code will show only the one category, but it will sort the categories by name.

```
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&show_count=1'); ?>
```